# No prints from the second thread - pthreads with mutex locks

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I wrote:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int globalVarX;

void *threadFunction (void *arg)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex1);

    while (globalVarX < 1000)
    {
        printf("x increment by thread id: %d", gettid ());
        ++globalVarX;
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex1);

    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t threadA;
    pthread_t threadB;

    if (pthread_create (&threadA, NULL, threadFunction, NULL)) 
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error creating thread\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (pthread_create (&threadB, NULL, threadFunction, NULL)) 
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error creating thread\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (pthread_join (threadA, NULL))
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error joining thread\n");
        return 2;
    }

    if (pthread_join (threadB, NULL))
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error joining thread\n");
        return 2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Prints I am getting are as follows:

```
~/studies$ ./a.out 
x increment by thread id: 3154
x increment by thread id: 3154
x increment by thread id: 3154
x increment by thread id: 3154
x increment by thread id: 3154
x increment by thread id: 3154
x increment by thread id: 3154
x increment by thread id: 3154
x increment by thread id: 3154
x increment by thread id: 3154
~/studies$
```

Prints from the other thread are not shown.

Comment: Remember that output to `stdout` (which is where `printf` writes) by default is line-buffered. That means the output will be flushed by a newline, so I suggest you edit the thread output to include a trailing newline in the `printf` call.

Comment: The output you show does not come form the code you show. The code does not print any new-lines from inside the `while`-loop.

Comment: Also the code invokes undefined behaviour by reading out the **uninitialised** variable `globalVarX`.

Comment: @alk , Global variables are initialized to 0.

Comment: @alk Per 6.7.8, paragraph 10 of the C standard (http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf): "If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then ... if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;"

Comment: @AndrewHenle, @CoolGuy: Yesyes, you all are right. I seem to suffer an allergic reaction on seeing patterns like `Type name;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thread increments `globalVarX` to `1000` and the second thread has nothing to do.

I suggest:

- Locking one increment instead of the whole loop.
- Give the other thread the opportunity to increment also by calling
  [`sched_yield()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sched_yield), because if one thread increments `globalVarX` to `1000` in its time slice there still would be no prints from the second thread.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int globalVarX;

void *threadFunction (void *arg)
{
    int flagbreak = 0;

    for(;!flagbreak;) {
        pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex1);
        if (globalVarX >= 1000) flagbreak = 1;
        else {
            ++globalVarX;
            printf("x increment by thread id: %ld\n", syscall(SYS_gettid));
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex1);
        sched_yield();
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t threadA;
    pthread_t threadB;

    if (pthread_create (&threadA, NULL, threadFunction, NULL)) 
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error creating thread\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (pthread_create (&threadB, NULL, threadFunction, NULL)) 
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error creating thread\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (pthread_join (threadA, NULL))
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error joining thread\n");
        return 2;
    }

    if (pthread_join (threadB, NULL))
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error joining thread\n");
        return 2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The call to `sched_yield()` isn't necessary.

Comment: @alk: And what if one thread is able to increment `globalVarX` to `1000` in its time slice, the second thread has still nothing to do and the output would have no prints from the second thread.

Comment: ... then increase 1000 to 10000 to 100000 to  ... ;-) - however I should have commented  "***conceptually** not necessary*", yes.

Comment: Also I feel, messing around with the scheduler to solve a single process' issue is somehow unreasonable..

Comment: Am thankful to you for pointing out my virtual blindness. I couldn't see that thread b had nothing to do. @4566976

Answer (score 2):

To conceptually give both threads a chance on incrementing the counter use this:

Pseudo code:

```
Condition cond = condition_init;
Mutex mutex = mutex_init;

int counter = 0;

thread_func
{
  mutex_lock(mutex);

  while (counter < 1000)
  {
    ++counter;
    print thread, counter;
    condition_signal(cond);
    condition_wait(cond, mutex);
  }  

  condition_signal(cond);

  mutex_unlock(mutex);
}

main
{
  Thread thread_a = thread_create(thread_func);
  Thread thread_b = treadd_create(thread_func);

  thread_join(thread_a);
  thread_join(thread_b);
}
```